# SSL Redirection Fails

Tags: ssl, nginx

I have a server that runs both development and staging instances of a site and each version has to answer on ports 80 & 443. The staging instance -- there's only one -- works exactly as I'd expect, but the development instances -- configured for each user -- loads a given page on either protocol directly just fine, but if I'm on a page on one port and try to link to the other it fails.

My Config

```
  server {
    listen 80;
    server_name ~^dev\.(?<username>[^.]+)\.client\.tld\.net$
                ~^(?<username>[^.]+)\.client\.dev\.tld\.net$
                ~^(?<username>[^.]+)\.dev\.client\.tld\.net$;

    location / {
      rewrite ^(.*) http://$username.client.tld.net$1 permanent;
    }
  }
  # This is the primary host that will ultimately answer requests.
  server {
    listen      80;
    server_name ~^(?<username>[^.]+)\.client\.tld\.net$;
    root        /home/$username/client/www/app/webroot;
    index       index.php;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/client.sandbox.access.log;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/client.sandbox.error.log;

    location / {
      try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?url=$uri;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
      include /etc/nginx/conf/php;
    }

    include /etc/nginx/conf/expire_content;
    include /etc/nginx/conf/ignore;
  }

  server {
  listen 443 ssl;
  server_name ~^dev\.(?<username>[^.]+)\.client\.tld\.net$
              ~^(?<username>[^.]+)\.client\.dev\.tld\.net$
              ~^(?<username>[^.]+)\.dev\.client\.tld\.net$;

  location / {
    rewrite ^(.*) https://$username.client.tld.net$1 permanent;
  }
}
# This is the primary host that will ultimately answer requests.
server {
  listen      443 ssl;
  server_name ~^(?<username>[^.]+)\.client\.tld\.net$;
  root        /home/$username/client/www/app/webroot;
  index       index.php;

  include /etc/nginx/conf/ssl;

  access_log /var/log/nginx/client.sandbox.access.log;
  error_log  /var/log/nginx/client.sandbox.error.log;

  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?url=$uri;
  }

  location ~ \.php$ {
    include /etc/nginx/conf/php;
  }

  include /etc/nginx/conf/expire_content;
  include /etc/nginx/conf/ignore;
}
```

Any idea where I've borked up my config?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, there is no need to create four separate configurations, as both your servers (HTTP and HTTPS) have exactly the same body. You can use the `$scheme` variable which contains either `http` or `https` according to the context your're just working in (for the redirects). Secondly I don't see any `root` declaration in your `dev` configuration, also no certificates which might cause problems with browsers.

Other then that the configuration looks okay to me (well, you could move the `index` declaration to your `http` configuration; so you don't have to repeat it all the time).

Please check out the following (commented) example configuration I made up for you. Maybe it helps.

```
# Put this in http context!
index           index.php;

server {
  # One server configuration to rule them all!
  listen        80;
  listen        443 ssl;

  # Seems legit.
  server_name   ~^dev\.(?<username>[^.]+)\.client\.tld\.net$
                ~^(?<username>[^.]+)\.client\.dev\.tld\.net$
                ~^(?<username>[^.]+)\.dev\.client\.tld\.net$;

  # Where am I?
  #root          /home/$username/client/www/app/webroot;

  # No wildcard certificate? No need to specify /etc/nginx as all paths
  # in the configuration are relative to the installation path.
  #include       conf/ssl;

  location / {
    # May work as well, can't test.
    #rewrite ^(.*) $scheme://$server_name$1 permanent;
    rewrite ^(.*) $scheme://$username.client.tld.net$1 permanent;
  }
}

server {
  listen        80;
  listen        443 ssl;
  server_name   ~^(?<username>[^.]+)\.client\.tld\.net$;
  root          /home/$username/client/www/app/webroot;
  include       conf/ssl;
  access_log    /var/log/nginx/client.sandbox.access.log;
  error_log     /var/log/nginx/client.sandbox.error.log;

  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?url=$uri;
  }

  location ~ \.php$ {
    include     conf/php;
  }

  include       conf/expire_content;
  include       conf/ignore;
}
```